# Can Joomla have a different URL for backend management?

Tags: url, security, joomla

My site will be maintained mostly by myself, and maybe 1 or 2 others. I want to know if it's possible if the back end can be managed from a different folder structure?

ie. `www.example.com` <- user sees content here.

`www.example.com/admin-portal/joomla/` <- backend here.

Basically users will never know where the admin portal is.

Comment: Trying to play games like that with a CMS doesn’t ever really prevent security issues since most hacking attempts—and successes—happen because of flaws in the overall CMS structure & not just the admin page. So if your system is public to the world—like most systems—it will be at risk.

Comment: This question might be a good question to ask on the [new Joomla Stack Exchange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/). However, like JMC suggests below, I don't think this is realistically possible unfortunately. I think that perhaps the better solution is to simply restrict access (by IP, etc.) to the administrator backend if possible.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know much about the newest versions of joomla, but looking this up on the web shows that some features of the admin portal are hard-coded to the default admin URL. People recommend password protecting the admin directory through `.htaccess` for better security. The other option is to use extensions, but as a general rule I hate using extensions to change core functionality, because it can make upgrades tedious.

Sources:

- http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=432&t=611287
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751525/how-can-i-change-joomla-admin-url

Comment: Exactly, I only know of extensions and having dealt with those in WordPress, made upgrades really awful. Looks like I'll stay away from using a CMS and build my own then. Thanks!

Comment: If you have the skills to build your own CMS it should be easier to use those skills to make a CMS more secure than out of the box.

Comment: @bybe, I agree with you, but he probably means a static html,css,js site.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recent version of Joomla you can use the well respected A[keeba AdminTools](https://www.akeebabackup.com/download/admin-tools.html), which in it's latest version added Admin cloaking to the free version.